# Why am I loosing keyboard control in Remmina?

Tags: 14.04, keyboard, remote-desktop, remmina

I am taking an online course that requires me to log in to a remote Windows server, and I am doing so using **Remmina Remote Desktop Client**. Once I am working on the remote server everything is fine, but if I switch to another application on my own computer, and switch back to Remmina, I can no longer type. The mouse still works to navigate the remote machine, and the keys work as shortcuts for some menu items, but I cannot type in any text areas. Control R seems to be bound to 'grab keyboard' on Remmina (I am not exactly sure what that means...), but pressing it does nothing. Every once in a while, and seemingly at random, I will regain the ability to type, but normally I have to quit Remmina and log in again. I am sure there is a simple solution to this, but I have not been able to find it so far.

I am using Remmina version 0.9.99.1, and Ubuntu 14.04. Thank you!

Comment: this is still an issue on Ubuntu 19.10; Remmina 1.4.3 git hash 688f5f75

Comment: I restarted Remmina, that solved it for me

Answer (score 2):

I had this pop up again after upgrade from XUbuntu 18.04 to 20.04. I am attaching an image of my setting from `remmina-preferences-rdp` that fixed it for me.

[image: screenshot]

I don't understand why, but the 100% setting and unchecking use client keyboard mapping fixed it for me in 18.04 and 20.04.

Comment: Slightly different issue.  Multiple RDP sessions deep I was losing all keystrokes except spacebar, delete and enter keys.  This fixed that too!  :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with remmina(verion 1.4.2), I fixed it sending a hello world. Remmina has an option in *Tools/Keystrokes/Send hello world* after that the keyboard works very well.